# How to load and use root_url in Rails helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

In my Rails application_helper.rb file, I have a function that need to use root_url:

```
def get_post_link(post)
    host = root_url
    post_link = host + 'posts/' + post.id.to_s

    return post_link
end
```

But then, when I am using this function, I will now get an error like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `posts_path' for #<Module:0x007fa8978e54a8>
```

I search around for solution and I stumble upon this:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

But when I include this line, another error comes out which is this:

```
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

I know that I could simply supply the :host parameter to the root_url to solve this problem like this: `root_url(:host => "localhost:3000")` but this just defeating the purpose of why I wanna use the root_url in the first place. This is because I am now just hardcoding the root_url and there is no way for the code to intelligently know whether I want the production server url or my localhost url like it originally suppose to do.

So, is there any other way to do this? So i could correctly use the `root_url` in my application_helper?

Thanks!

Comment: Please screenshot of your error.

Comment: You can define the following in your environment files: in config/development.rb `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'` and then in the config/production.rb : `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'your_domain.com'`

Comment: Also, the `get_post_link(post)` method is likely to be an already existing method of Rails (generated via the Route helpers). This method could be replaced with `post_url(post)`

Comment: The two things that you might want to try also are adding `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to the top of the helper, to me that seems hacky. I was wondering if it could find the root_path. Though I agree with @MrYoshiji that the correct way to do it is just to say `post_url(path)`

Comment: thanks all. Now i got this error: `arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation`